# How to make a Torrent client keep the same torrent data for multiple users?

Tags: users, file-sharing, bittorrent

I'm running Linux Mint with two user accounts. One account has admin priviliges while another is a normal account.

If I start a torrent download in admin account I want that to continue even in the other account and vice-versa. So, basically I want a torrent client to have the same app data for both accounts. I'm currently using Ktorrent.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) instead. You can run it as a daemon process and then connect to it using a web browser on port :9001. This is what I do so that multiple users can connect to the same instance and manage the single instance.

*screenshot of web client - click image for larger view*

[image: ss of web client]

You can also use a dedicated fat client version that will connect to the remote daemon so that you can manage it.

*screenshot of fat client - click image for larger view*

[image: ss of fat client]

Comment: Can you give me more details on how to do this. If I install "Transmission daemon" isn't it going to store the torrent file data separately like other torrent clients. App data seems to be different for each user for all programs. Why is Transmission an exception?

Comment: It's meant to run as a service, so when you operate on the files thru it, they're written as the owner of the daemon, typically root, but it could be run as some other user, such as transmission. You could create a group that transmission and other users are members of if you want to have them all deal w/ the files from the filesystem's perspective.